# Uitableview reuse cell issues

Tags: iphone, uitableview

Iam performing an addition operation in `UITableView` from `UITableViewCell` as i scroll the tableview im loosing the value in the first `UITableViewCell` and though getting a wrong result,how can i hold the value in first `UITableViewCell` and get added with the value in last `UITableViewCell`

Comment: Please add the relevant code to your question

Answer (score 0):

For UITableViewCell reuse issue if you are adding the UILabel, UIImageView, UITextField etc in UITableViewCell programmatically then follow the code given below.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UIImageView *img_view;
UILabel *name_lbl;
UILabel *date_lbl;
UIImageView *status_imageview;

UITableViewCell *cell = [aTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {

    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

    img_view=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(OFFSET,OFFSET,IMAGEWIDTH,50)];
     // Set Image view Properties
    img_view.tag = 101;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:pimg_view];


    name_lbl= [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5*OFFSET+IMAGEWIDTH,5,200,25)];
   //Set UILabel properties
    pname_lbl.tag = 202;
    [cell addSubview:name_lbl];

    date_lbl= [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5*OFFSET+IMAGEWIDTH,30,200,25)];
    date_lbl.tag = 303;
    [cell addSubview:date_lbl];

 }else{

     img_view = (UIImageView *)[(cell)viewWithTag:101];
     name_lbl = (UILabel *)[(cell)viewWithTag:202];
     date_lbl = (UILabel *)[(cell)viewWithTag:303];
}


name_lbl.text = @"Set the Value accordingly";
date_lbl.text =  @"Set the Value accordingly";
[img_view setImage:@"Set the image accordingly"];

cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

return cell;
}
```